# Invalid Cast Exception ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Heres the overall code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class partin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private List<String> books = new List<String>();

void Page_PreRender()
{
    Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
    Item_Listbox.DataBind();   
}

int SortASC(string x, string y)
{
    return String.Compare(x, y);
}

int SortDESC(string x, string y)
{
    return String.Compare(x, y) * -1;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        Header_Label.Text = "Welcome! Please select a book category.";
        Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
        Item_Listbox.DataBind();

    }

}

protected void Fiction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        Header_Label.Text = "Fiction Section";

        books.Add("Title: The Old Man and The Sea | Decription: An epic novel. | Price: 10 USD | Quantity: 3");
        books.Add("Title: A Game of Thrones | Decription: A tale of fire and ice. | Price: 15 USD | Quantity: 6");
        books.Add("Title: Dracula | Decription: A book about vampires. | Price: 5 USD | Quantity: 7");
        books.Add("Title: Twilight | Decription: An awful book. | Price: Free | Quantity: 1000");

        Item_Listbox.DataSource = books;
        Item_Listbox.DataBind();

        ViewState["books"] = books;

}


protected void Non_Fiction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Header_Label.Text = "Non-Fiction Section";



}
protected void Self_Help_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Header_Label.Text = "Self Help Section";



}

protected void Sort_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Sort")
    {
        switch (e.CommandArgument.ToString())
        {
            case "ASC":
                books.Sort(SortASC);
                break;
            case "DESC":
                books.Sort(SortDESC);
                break;
        }

    }
    if (ViewState["books"] == null)
        ViewState["books"] = new string[0];

    Item_Listbox.DataSource = new List<string>((string[])ViewState["books"]);
    Item_Listbox.DataBind();  
}



}
```

The Invalid Cast Exception being thrown here:

```
Item_Listbox.DataSource = new List<string>((string[])ViewState["books"]);
```

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET so I'm lost as to what may causing it, fixes welcome!

Comment: What is that line supposed to do? Don't you want just `Item_Listbox.DataSource = ViewState["books"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because you are doing

```
private List<String> books = new List<String>();
//...
ViewState["books"] = books;
```

and then you are trying to cast `List<string>` to `string[]`

```
Item_Listbox.DataSource = new List<string>((string[])ViewState["books"]);
```

Rewriting last line in the following way **should solve the issue**:

```
Item_Listbox.DataSource = (List<string>)ViewState["books"];
```

Or even

```
Item_Listbox.DataSource = ViewState["books"];
```

And second place where you have following code:

```
if (ViewState["books"] == null)
        ViewState["books"] = new string[0];
```

**If** statement results to false, since ViewState was already set after button click, but in general I would suggest to be consistent with the data structures you're using and change this code to the following:

```
if (ViewState["books"] == null)
        ViewState["books"] = new List<string>();
```

Comment: The cast is not necessary. And it won't work for the case where `ViewState["books"]` is set to `new string[0]`.

Comment: OK, with that correction I still am running into the issue I had posted in another thread that when I hit the button to do ASC or DESC (after clicking the fiction button and populating the listbox) it will then clear the listbox instead of putting it in ASC or DESC order. Thanks for the help so far! Any suggestion on this error though?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 places where you set "books":
`ViewState["books"] = books;` where `books = new List<String>();`.

`ViewState["books"] = new string[0];`

Answer (score 0):

`ViewState["books"]` is `List<string>`, not `string[]`.  Remove the (string[]) and it should work.  In fact, you can probably remove the new List( ), too.